# Question on the proof of the inverse function theorem

Tags: inverse-function-theorem

I was reading the proof [here](http://people.math.sc.edu/schep/InversefunctionThm.pdf) for the inverse function theorem. I understand everything except in the middle of page 2, the proof says

$$\sum^n_{i=1}-2(f_i(x_0) - y_i) \frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{x_j}}(x_0) = 0$$

Since we know that $det(Df(x_0))$ is not zero and thus invertible,  $f_i(x_0) - y_i = 0$.

This is used to show that $f$ maps an open set to an open set. My question: since $Df(x_0)$ is invertible so it only maps from $0$ to $0$. Then what prevents $x_0$ from being $0$?

Comment: Well, $x_0$ can be $0$, why not? What would be the problem then?

Comment: How can I get $f_i(x_0) = y_i$?

Comment: I think there's confusion about $Df(x_0)$ being a linear transformation. $Df(x_0)(y)$ is linear in $y$, not linear in $x_0$. So $Df(0)\neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Regard ${z_i}:=-2(f_i(x_0)-y_i)$ and let $\vec{z}=(z_1,z_2.\cdots,z_n)$ as a vector. Now, that expression above is the matrix $Df(x_0)$ multiplied into $z$. Since this product is zero and derivative matrix is nonsingular, we get $z=0$.